# I have a named function which works great on click. How can I run it on a specific element when the page loads?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I have a function called runFilter. It works great when I run it on click. If you look at the line underneath "on load, run the filter," that doesn't work at all. If it was a built-in function like .css() then it would work fine, but this isn't a built-in function and I've already failed at extending jQuery to make it one.

I'm probably doing something very obvious wrong here, but what I want to happen is for the function to fire once after the page is loaded, targeting this specific link: ul > li:first-child a.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {

    function runFilter( event ) {

        console.log( this );

        event.preventDefault();

        //* add active class on the active nav item
        $( 'ul.attractions-filters a' ).removeClass( 'active' );
        $( this ).addClass( 'active' ); 

        //* add active class for visible things
        term = $( this ).attr( 'data-term' );
        $( '.type-attractions' ).removeClass( 'active' );
        $( '.attractiontype-' + term ).addClass( 'active' );
    }

    // Show everything once the page is fully loaded
    $( '.type-attractions' ).addClass( 'active' );

    //* On load, run the filter
    // $( 'ul.attractions-filters:first a' ).on( 'load', runFilter );

    //* On click, run the filter
    $( 'ul.attractions-filters a' ).on( 'click', runFilter );

});
```

Comment: To clarify: it works correctly when a click event happens. What I'm having trouble with is targeting the first child of a list (the link inside of it), then doing exactly the same thing that would happen if that link were clicked on – but doing it immediately when the page loads.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You're very close!

Your code, modified below, with a few comments:

```
// altered to be a briefer document ready (Still no-conflict safe!)
jQuery(function( $ ) {
    function runFilter( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // add active class on the active nav item
        $( 'ul.attractions-filters a' ).removeClass( 'active' );
        $( this ).addClass( 'active' ); 

        // add active class for visible things
        term = $( this ).attr( 'data-term' );
        $( '.type-attractions' ).removeClass( 'active' );
        $( '.attractiontype-' + term ).addClass( 'active' );
    }

    // Show everything once the page is fully loaded
    $( '.type-attractions' ).addClass( 'active' );

    // On click, run the filter
    $( 'ul.attractions-filters a' ).on( 'click', runFilter );

    // NOTE: Choose ONE of the following three methods:
    // Method #1: using trigger
    $( 'ul.attractions-filters:first a' ).trigger( 'click' );

    // Method #2: using click
    $( 'ul.attractions-filters:first a' ).click();

    // Method #3: better yet "chain" the methods to reduce duplicate code...
    // NOTE: this replaces BOTH your .on('click') AND the .trigger or .click above...
    $( 'ul.attractions-filters a' )
        .on( 'click', runFilter )
        .trigger( 'click');
});
```

Comment: So, if I'm reading this correctly, the .trigger( 'click' ) sort of simulates a click? Is that right?

Comment: @JonSchroeder - yes, `.trigger('click')` _triggers_ the `click` event for the element.

Answer (score 0):

While it's not clear which `A` of which `UL` you're actually trying to refer to, there are a bunch of different ways of doing it:

The example below depends on a few things:

1. jQuery will call any method attached through `.on` via the `.click`
   method.  It automatically binds it to the function.
2. jQuery will let you invoke known events through the `.trigger` method.  It automatically binds it to the function
3. `querySelector` only returns the first element that matches a selector (may be easier to read than the equivalent jQuery selector)

```js
let selector = 'ul.attractions-filters a';
let firstSelector = 'ul.attractions-filters:first a';
let firstChildSelector = 'ul.attractions-filters a:first';
let firstChildSelectorJQ = 'ul.attractions-filters:first a:first';
let whatYouAskedFor = 'ul > li:first-child a'

$(function() {
  function runFilter() {
    console.log(this)
  }

  $(selector).on('click', runFilter);
  
  console.log( "This selector will click all A elements in the first UL with class 'attractions-filters'")
  $(firstSelector).click();
  $(firstSelector).trigger('click');

  console.log( "This selector will click the first A element in every UL with class 'attractions-filters'")
  $(whatYouAskedFor).click();
  $(whatYouAskedFor).trigger('click');

  console.log("These selectors will click the first A element in the first UL with class 'attractions-filters'")
  $($(firstSelector)[0]).click();
  $($(firstSelector)[0]).trigger('click');
  $(firstChildSelector).click();
  $(firstChildSelector).trigger('click');
  runFilter.bind($(firstSelector)[0])();

  console.log("These selectors will select only the first child of the first UL of class 'attractions-filters' and click it")
  $(firstChildSelectorJQ).click();
  $(firstChildSelectorJQ).trigger('click');
  runFilter.bind($(firstChildSelectorJQ)[0])();
  runFilter.bind(document.querySelector(selector))();

  console.log("This selector is the requirement you gave")
  runFilter.bind(document.querySelector(whatYouAskedFor))();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li><a href="#what?">What You Asked For</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="attractions-filters">
<li><a href="#first">UL 1, LI 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#second">UL 1, LI 2</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="attractions-filters">
<li><a href="#third">UL 2, LI 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#fourth">UL 2, LI 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @cale_b Unfortunately, that is also the [recommended](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) way to call jQuery's `ready` feature, not to mention the OP does not provide the HTML he's invoking the function against

Comment: This is part of a WordPress plugin/theme, which is the reason for the odd docReady statement.

Comment: @tibrogargan, thank you for your help. It was very helpful to see both recommendations using .trigger and helped push me in the right direction.

Comment: @JonSchroeder You need to clarify your question.